# Unity - Save Progress In Game?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, save

Hi I am creating a small game with Unity3d. But now I have trouble saving some variables. Now I am using the following code

```
void Awake(){
proiettili  = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PallottoleOgniSecondo");
}

void OnApplicationQuit(){
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("PallottoleOgniSecondo", proiettili);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

This way I can save the variable, but only when I try on unity, if I try does not work on Android.
you know how I can fix?

Comment: You want to look into binary formatters and serialization. I've tried this on PC and Android and it works for me. http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-save-and-load-your-players-progress-in-unity--cms-20934

Comment: Ok thanks, but what you mean with binary formatters?

Comment: A binary formatter will serialize/deserialize your object into/from a binary format. It's how you can save/load your object. This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746380/saving-loading-unity3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it for an example class called MyClass

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

[Serializable]
public class MyClass {

    public int myInt;

    public void Save(){
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create (FilePath());
        bf.Serialize(file, this);
        file.Close();
    }

    public void Load(){
        if(File.Exists(FilePath())){
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(FilePath(), FileMode.Open);
            MyClass loaded = bf.Deserialize(file) as Brochure;
            myInt = loaded.myInt;
        }
    }

    static string FilePath()
    {
        return Application.persistentDataPath + "/myClass.dat";
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to create another c sharp script insert this?

Comment: This is an example with a class called MyClass. You need to: copy the Save and Load methods in your own, and modify the load at the end to get the right information from the loaded object. Also you need to add serializable to your class.

Answer (score 0):

You should try it like this

```
  PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score",ScoreManager.score);
  PlayerPrefs.Save();
  score=PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score");
```

I've tried this in my project for a Web and WebGL build, if you need to know about serialization I could give you an example

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions of Android project,if you had added "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".